# ssrs tables not responding to value selection from the parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have three tables in SSRS each of them using different data set and I have one parameter "Region" under that I have a list of regions my question is when I select different values from the parameter the value in the tables is giving me the same result I don't know where am wrong please help I am new to SSRS plus to this community as well . Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply more information. Show how you have attempted to apply the parameter (in the dataset query? in the table filters? etc.). Anything that might be relevant, screen shots, your dataset query (as text) etc.. The solution is probably simple but without more info, it's guesswork. Please also read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It will help you get better answers.

Comment: Did you create a Filter on the dataset or table that uses the parameter?